# MySQL: Return the Highest Monthly Selling product with Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, subquery, max

I'm trying to write a query which is supposed to return the highest selling product per month. There are 4 different products.

The table **Product_Sales** has 3 attributes: Product_ID (4 types), Purchase_ID (Unique and 1 Purchase per product) and Purchase_Date:

I have a current query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Purchase_Date) as "Month",  Product_ID, Count(*) as "Sales_Amount"
FROM Product_Sales
GROUP BY MONTH(Purchase_Date), MONTHNAME(Purchase_Date)
ORDER BY MONTH(Purchase_Date);
```

This currently returns:

```
+------------+----------+--------------+
|    Month   |Product_ID| Sales_Amount |
+------------+----------+--------------+
|   January  |    1     |      220     |
|   January  |    2     |      192     |
|   January  |    3     |      288     |
|   January  |    4     |      173     |
|  February  |    1     |      252     |
|  February  |    2     |      199     |
...etc.
```

I can see by looking at the table which Product sold the most in each month. But I'm trying to make a query which only returns the highest selling product for that month, so the month name, product id and amount of sales for that product that month. I haven't been able to use the MAX method. I would like it to return this instead:

```
+------------+----------+--------------+
|    Month   |Product_ID| Sales_Amount |
+------------+----------+--------------+
|   January  |    3     |      288     |
|   February |    1     |      252     |
|    March   |    3     |      288     |
|    April   |    2     |      343     |
|     May    |    1     |      272     |
etc...
```

I'm not sure if this would require me to make a function or a subquery.

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: 8.0.12 @P.Salmon

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using MySQL version 8.0 or higher, You may use window function -

```
SELECT Month, Product_ID, Sales_Amount
FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(Purchase_Date) as "Month"
            ,Product_ID
            ,Count(*) as "Sales_Amount"
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MONTHNAME(Purchase_Date) ORDER BY MONTH(Purchase_Date) DESC) RN
      FROM Product_Sales
      GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Purchase_Date)
              ,Product_ID
      ORDER BY MONTH(Purchase_Date)) X
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: 'GROUP BY MONTH(Purchase_Date), MONTHNAME(Purchase_Date)' ? Count(*) as "Sales_Amount" ? Sum possibly?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Gives me "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @AllenPeck, Please try now.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've tried again but it still gives the Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Sales_Database.Product_Sales.ProductID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @AllenPeck, Please try now.